# User Control c# Add Dynamically

Tags: c#, controls, picturebox

I create a user control dynamically in my code

```
UserControl myobject = new UserControl();
```

myObject contains a button etc.
when I add this control to my picturebox

```
picturebox.Controls.Add(myobject);
```

my picturebox's backgorund image is dissappeared.

Why?

note: the button can be seen however. I want picturebox to be seen also

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set transparent basckground color of your user control. This will make picturebox visible:

```
UserControlDisplay myobject = new UserControlDisplay();
myobject.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
picturebox.Controls.Add(myobject);
```

BTW I believe you have different name of user control. And yes, as @samjudson stated, PictureBox should not be used this way: try to use `Panel` with background image instead (approach will stay same - use transparent color to see parent control):

```
panel.BackgroundImage = // your image
UserControlDisplay myobject = new UserControlDisplay();
myobject.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
panel.Controls.Add(myobject);
```

Comment: This is worked for me thank you :) Yes I have a different name, "UserControlDisplay". I only try to make my question simple =)

Comment: I control in every second that: read database, clear picturebox controls than add the controls again. This is for updating the picturebox which is a basic map actually. If I clear panel, than map will dissappear and appear again. that was why I used to add delete controls to picturebox

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
UserControl myobject = new UserControl();
Button but = new Button();
but.BackColor = Color.Gray
pic.BackColor = Color.Green;
myobject.Controls.Add(but);
pic.Visible = true;
pic.Controls.Add(myobject);
```

Answer (score 1):

The PictureBox control is not meant to be used as a container. Try adding a parent Panel or similar and the adding the PictureBox and your custom control to the Panel control.

Comment: you mean-> mypanel.control.add(myObject); than say picturebox.control.add(mypanel)

Comment: I control in every second that: read database, clear picturebox controls than add the controls again. This is for updating the picturebox which is a basic map actually. If I clear panel, than map will dissappear and appear again. that was why I used to add delete controls to picturebox –